# No visible @interface for 'WeightEntry' declares the selector 'initWithEntity:insertInToManagedObjectContext:

Tags: xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobject

Im not really sure what im doing wrong. I get this error message "No visible @interface for 'WeightEntry' declares the selector 'initWithEntity:insertInToManagedObjectContext:". But my WeightEntry class inherites from NSManagedObject so that method should be inherited.

The code is posted [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/81707637/Health%20Beat.zip)

Thanks for all the help in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you have written it right? It should be insertIntoManagedObjectContext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`insertInToManagedObjectContext` should be `insertIntoManagedObjectContext`.

Comment: Thank you that fixed everything